# Binding list to data repeater

Tags: c#, list, datarepeater

I am trying to bind a list to data repeater in C#.  the basic code works:

```
List<string> arrlist = new List<string>();
arrlist.Add("item 1");
arrlist.Add("item 2");
arrlist.Add("item 3");
arrlist.Add("item 4");
arrlist.Add("item 5");
dataRepeater1.DataSource = arrlist;
dataRepeater1.DataBind();
```

But when I try to Bind the the list to the data repeater, Visual Studio 2010 is not familiar with the subroutine .DataBind()  and that's why the next order can not be debugged.
How can I bind the list to the data repeater?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.datarepeater.datasource.aspx) states:

> Setting the DataSource property of the DataRepeater control has no
>   effect. The DataSource properties of the child controls determine what
>   is displayed at run time.

I believe you should be adding controls to the DataRepeater. It is the child controls of the DataRepeater that should bound to your data source.

See:

- [How to: Display Bound Data in a DataRepeater Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488274.aspx)
- [How to: Add Custom Controls to the Data Sources Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5554bf3a.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As show [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1th73f0.aspx#Y312), you can use DataBind with VB. Probably you explaination error is not so clear.

Comment: I am writing the code in C# not in VB (sorry for the mistake, I meant to write Visual Studio 2010 and not VB2010).  the subroutine .DataBind () is not working in C#.  I think .DataBindings() suppose to work in C# but I can not understand which variables the subroutine needs. How do I bind the data repeater (or a check box that i have on the data repeater) with a data source?

Answer (score 0):

The dataRepeater control is a winforms control and winforms do not have the DataBind() method like ASP.NET webforms do.